# startActivityForResult extrange behavior

Tags: android

I cannot see what is wrong in my code:

I have an activity (lets call it; A) that starts another activity (B) in this way:

In A:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ...
    gridOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long 
            intent = new Intent(ReproductorActivity.this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, B.RESULT_PATH);
    }
}
```

I have in a OnLongItemClickListener asigned to B' listview with this onItemLongClick

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    ctx.onLongClick(arg2);
    return false;
}
```

Being ctx the B object owner of the OnLongItemClickListener and onLongClick this method in class B:

```
public void onLongClick(int arg2) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("PATH", getItem(arg2));
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

And I also have a callback function in A like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){               
    if (requestCode == B.RESULT_PATH) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ... get data, do stuff....                   
        }
    }
}
```

So, my problem is that it didn't work. It shows B but does nothing when is back...

I've debug it and when I click the element of the grid in the the class A its OnItemClickListener's `onItemClick` is called but, after this, the A's `onActivityResult` is called and after of this it appears B activity. I longclick in a item of B and it does the `onLongClick(int)` but there's no callback in `A.onActivityResult`...

I dont know what happens, any idea? any clue?

Thanks.

Edit: When OnActivityResult is called, requestCode == B.RESULT_PATH

Comment: So, what is the problem again?

Comment: I want to launch B and get a response from B in A's OnActivityResult but A.OnActivityResult is called before I longclickk the item in B....

Answer (score 0):

In onActivityResult there should be requestCode instead of resultCode in the first if statement:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){               
    if (requestCode == FileSelector.RESULT_PATH) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ... get data, do stuff....                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rigth, fixed that, the question is that I only reach OnActivityResult before B appears (more specically, when I've debug I've see that before it ends its onCreate).